# Optimize Window queries in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

I have a products table with approximately 17,000,000 records.

```
CREATE TABLE vendor_prices (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  vendor integer NOT NULL,
  sku character varying(25) NOT NULL,
  category_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  price numeric(8,5) NOT NULL,
  effective_date timestamp without time zone,
  expiration_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT (now() + '1 year'::interval)
);
```

Most of the records are redundant and I keep a separate table with only the relevant records. I effectively remove duplicate records using [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/101849/66716) on *dba.stackexchange*.

Here is the core of the query *(using `select` instead of `delete`)*:

```
select * from (   
    SELECT id,
        rate = lag(price) OVER w
        AND (lead(id) OVER w) IS NOT NULL AS del
      FROM vendor_prices
      WHERE vendor = 516

      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY effective_date, id)
) d
   WHERE NOT d.del
```

The problem though I'm having, is that it takes way too long to execute, especially for vendors with lot's of records. This particular vendor in this query `WHERE vendor = 516` has some 3M rows of which only around 80K are not redundant. What can I do to improve this query.

Here is the results doing `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=987648.74..987648.75 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=38220.825..38220.825 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on d  (cost=862040.12..983596.85 rows=1620756 width=0) (actual time=31758.342..38211.262 rows=84245 loops=1)
        Filter: (NOT d.del)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3094780
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=862040.12..951181.72 rows=3241513 width=25) (actual time=31758.220..37929.024 rows=3179025 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=862040.12..870143.90 rows=3241513 width=25) (actual time=31758.196..34952.249 rows=3179025 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: vendor_prices.sku, vendor_prices.effective_date, vendor_prices.id
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 123448kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on vendor_prices  (cost=60790.16..356386.08 rows=3241513 width=25) (actual time=350.911..1512.974 rows=3179025 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (vendor = 516)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=47546
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_vendor_number  (cost=0.00..59979.79 rows=3241513 width=0) (actual time=336.936..336.936 rows=3179025 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (vendor = 516)
```

ps. I have a `multicolumn index` as suggested by @Erwin in his answer:

- A [**multicolumn index**] on `(vendor, sku, effective_date, id)` would be perfect for this - in this particular order.

but it's using `idx_vendor_number` as you can see in the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which is only on the `vendor` column

Comment: `external merge  Disk: 123448kB` is your biggest problem. Try to increase `work_mem` until this is done in memory.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you - increased work_mem to 512Meg and it shaved a dozen or so seconds off total by doing merge in memory. It helps but what we really need is improvement by a magnitude at least.